# XMPP File transfert with gloox

Tags: c++, xmpp, gloox

I'm currently working with gloox in order to send XMPP messages from my C++ program. I work in local network with my private prosody XMPP server. 
Sending text messages between two client works but not files. I tried the gloox examples (ft_rcv & ft_send) but it did not worked neither (obviously I modified the examples to match my configuration), I always have the same error :

```
<error type='cancel'><service-unavailable xmlns='urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-stanzas'/>
```

At the beginning I thought it was due to my prosody server but I added the following lines in the conf files :

```
Component "proxy.jabberserver.local" "proxy65" 
    proxy65_address = "proxy.jabberserver.local" 
    proxy65_ports = { 7777 }
```

I tried different server and different port but I'm currently in a dead end. If someone have an idea it would be great.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

`f->addStreamHost( JID("proxy.jabberserver.local"), "proxy.jabberserver.local", 7777 );` should do the trick. If no - show full XML log.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It's what I already have in my sender and receiver but it's not working.